# How can I use free when I used ** ( double pointer )?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct, free

```
STUDENT ** list=NULL;
char *getid;
getid =(char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
printf("How many student? ");
int menuNum,num=0;

scanf("%d",&num);
list=(STUDENT**)malloc(num*sizeof(STUDENT*));
```

I used pointer like this. 
As I learned from the professor, before finishing my code, I ought to use free() function to retrieve the allocated memory again.

Here s what i wanna ask you.

I learned that If i wanna use free() about (char *getid)

I know I should write

```
free(getid);
```

then How can I use free about

```
STUDENT ** list = NULL ; // **It's about struct**
```

Should I use like

```
free(list);
```

or

```
free(*list);
```

I think the former is right, but when I write like the latter, there's no error on my X-code.

Could you tell me about it ?

Comment: `free(list);`. Each time you do `X = malloc(Y)`; you do `free(X)` later.

Comment: Basic priniciple: store result of malloc in a pointer variable, free that pointer. What is unclear?

Comment: Should I write malloc and write free() immediately? not in the end of the line?

Comment: Since you haven't allocated space for `list[i]` for any i, list is currently pointing to a bunch of uninitialized pointers.  you will need to to `list[i] = malloc ( ....` before you can use any of them.  Then, when you are done, you will do `free(list[i])` for all i and then `free(list)`

Comment: @CNotice _Should I write malloc and write free() immediately? not in the end of the line?_ could you clarify? You call free when you want to free the memory, and only then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

```
free(list);
```

> but when I write like free(*list);, there's no error on my X-code

That's why `*list` does not deallocate anything, since nothing is allocated there. However, your program suffers from a memory leak that way, since the memory pointed to by the double pointer named `list` is not free'd. However, you are just (un)lucky not to see your program crash.

If you used [Valgrind](http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/valgrind.html) though, you would see the memory leak.

> Should I write malloc and write free() immediately? not in the end of the line?

No. You first allocate the memory dynamically with `malloc()`, then you use this memory (initialize, access, etc.) and when you do not need the memory anymore, and only then, you deallocate it with `free()`.

---

However, if you had dynamically allocated space for `list[i]`, then you should do:

```
free(list[i]);
free(list);
```

where the order matters, since you do not want to have tangling pointers!

Maybe my [example](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/2d-dynamic-array-c/) on dynamically allocated a 2D array will more explanatory on this, even though it's a different data structure than a list.

---

PS: We [don't cast what malloc returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Then If i free(list[i]); i should call this by using for loop?

Comment: Yes @CNotice, just like in the 2D array example I linked above. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You should free any memory allocated by malloc with free...

as you figured out, you requested 8 bytes of memory and saved the Pointer to it to your symbol `getid` (`getid =(char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);`)

as for your list, this is a bit trickier:
You actually allocating a list of pointers that should point to other memory locations (those might be dynamically allocated as well)

`list=(STUDENT**)malloc(num*sizeof(STUDENT*));` size of `num` pointers
Allocates the space for the list and saves the pointer to it at symbol `list`.

I'd remind that the memory allocated doesn't have to come initialized from the OS, so we should initialize it.

```
for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
{
   list[i] = NULL;
}
```

You could also use `memset(list, NULL, num * sizeof(STUDENT*))`.

and you are very much correct you should free its memory by `free(list)`,
But you should free the items in the list BEFORE you free the list of pointers itself. (again, if the items were dynamically allocated!)

```
for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
{
   if(list[i] != NULL) // only if allocated.
   {
      free(list[i]); // free the element @ position i
      list[i] = NULL;
   }
}
```

Comment: the `free()` function properly handles the case of being passed a NULL pointer, so no need to check if the `list[i]` is not NULL.

Comment: is it by definition? i m always wery that different Clibs will act differently.

Comment: you might want to read the `man` page for `free()`, which includes the statement: *If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed.*

Comment: @user3629249 then don i have to call all free(list[i])?

Comment: @CNotice You Do! In my answer, before i call `free(list[i])` i check for nulls, in order to prevent from deallocating invalid memory pointer. t @user3629249 pointed out that the method `free(void*)` is doing the check already, so my `if(list[i]==NULL)` is redundant.

Comment: Then as a result, Should I write like this? Free(list[I])and Free(list)?

Comment: I used this list[i]->a .... like this So i should free(list[i]) , and hen free(list) ? Right?